# how to read data on each line in a file and and determine which one of the data correspond to a bench mark in a shell script

Tags: linux

I have a file with many lines of different data. I want to read each data on each line and determine which of them correspond to the bench mark. i.e

```
-0.002345
-0.109873
 0.0
-2.04555
-0.00001
 0.34444
 0.89999
```

and the bench mark is (+ or -) 0.00001.

Comment: What do you expect as output? List of files that contain `0.00001` preceded by `-` or a space?

Comment: @choroba, i want the first line that have either +or- 0.00001 as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file consists of lines like:

```
-0.002345 -0.109873  0.0 -2.04555 -0.00001  0.34444  0.89999
```

And you want to find every line in `inputfile` that is the exact same, you could use for example `awk`. A very quick and dirty solution could look something like this:

```
awk '{if($1=="-0.002345" && $2=="-0.109873" && $3=="0.0" && $4=="-2.04555" && $5=="-0.00001" && $6==" 0.34444" && $7=="0.89999"){ print $0 } }' inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`. If you only want the first line of each file, you can specify the `-m` option:

```
grep -m1 '^[- ]0.00001' files
```